# Is it okay to write a post Introducing a tool?

Tags: discussion, support

I have just developed a new bioinformatic tool and I was simply wondering whether it is okay to write a post introducing the tool?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, but only if you:

1. Post a question asking how to do something that your tool can serve as an answer to. This is strictly a Q&A site so *everything* needs to be posted as either a question or an answer.
2. Post an answer explaining how to install your tool, where to find it and an example that shows how to do whatever the question asked.
3. ***Clearly state that you are the author of the tool***. See [How not to be a spammer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).